# Elementary proof about nth differences of nth powers of integer

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, finite-differences

In a [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045987/how-to-prove-that-nth-differences-of-a-sequence-of-nth-powers-would-be-a-sequenc) on *Math.SE.*, a proof sketch was proposed for the proposition below:

*The sequence of $n$th differences of the sequence of $n$th powers of positive integers, is the constat sequence $n!$.*

Anyone familiar with algebraic identities and induction can understand that proof, but it's not the case for a 7th-grade students!

Is there an elementary proof for this proposition?

Thanks.

Comment: There is a purely combinatorial argument, which I give [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4801066/473276). With a lot of effort and simplification, and lots of examples and a slow build-up I think that might be accessible, or at least vaguely understandable for a talented 13-year-old.